# Presta Shop: new (second) copy of shop keeps redirecting to old domain

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I'm using standard presta shop intalation. Then I've made a copy (DB and FTP files) and setup a new subdomain pointing to it to provide myself test evn. But all http requests on my new test subdomain are still redirected to main domain.

I'm loking for a cause. Maybe it is a .htaccess problem (code below). In the end, when I'm entering my new instance of presta shop (http://tst-shop.mydomain.com) I don't want if to redirect me to main/old domain.
How to do that?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
```

Comment: FWIW this has nothing to do with your .htaccess file; there are no external redirects in your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check your copy for database entries in **ps_shop_url** table and fix "*domain*" and "*domain_ssl*" values to reflect your staging subdomain.

If your staging copy is in a subfolder, update the "physical_url" value from "*/*" to the subfolder name (do not forget the trailing slash in case  - Ie. */subfolder/* )

Then go in backoffice, "**Seo&Url**" section and save the configuration once to regenerate a clean *.htaccess* with updated paths.

Comment: Thanks! Actually as I use subdomain first step helped. Why should I do the third step? What those changes in .htaccess are for? BTW pls check if I pointed a correct Save button in admin panel, cause I kinda guess it.

Comment: The third step is the one that actually update the .htaccess with the correct / updated subdomain. This causes Prestashop to be aware of that and correctly rewrite URLs afterward.